# Disable JMX/MBeans in JVM

Tags: jvm, apache-kafka-connect, jmx, debezium, mbeans

I have two Debezium SQL Server connectors that have to connect to one database and publish two different tables. Their `name` and `database.history.kafka.topic` are unique. Still when adding the second one (using a POST request) I get below exceptions. I don't want to use a unique value for `database.server.name` which counterintuitively has been used for metric name.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to register the MBean 'debezium.sql_server:type=connector-metrics,context=schema-history,server=mydatabase'
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: debezium.sql_server:type=connector-metrics,context=schema-history,server=mydatabase
```

We won't be using JMX/MBeans so it's okay to disable it, but the question is how. If there is a common way to do it for JVM please advise.

I even see below code in Debezium where it registers a MBean. Looking just at two first lines, it seems one way to bypass this issue is forcing `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()` to return `null`. So another way of asking the same question may be how to force `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()` return `null`?

```
public synchronized void register() {
    try {
        final MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        if (mBeanServer == null) {
            LOGGER.info("JMX not supported, bean '{}' not registered", name);
            return;
        }
        // During connector restarts it is possible that Kafka Connect does not manage
        // the lifecycle perfectly. In that case it is possible the old metric MBean is still present.
        // There will be multiple attempts executed to register new MBean.
        for (int attempt = 1; attempt <= REGISTRATION_RETRIES; attempt++) {
            try {
                mBeanServer.registerMBean(this, name);
                break;
            }
            catch (InstanceAlreadyExistsException e) {
                if (attempt < REGISTRATION_RETRIES) {
                    LOGGER.warn(
                            "Unable to register metrics as an old set with the same name exists, retrying in {} (attempt {} out of {})",
                            REGISTRATION_RETRY_DELAY, attempt, REGISTRATION_RETRIES);
                    final Metronome metronome = Metronome.sleeper(REGISTRATION_RETRY_DELAY, Clock.system());
                    metronome.pause();
                }
                else {
                    LOGGER.error("Failed to register metrics MBean, metrics will not be available");
                }
            }
        }
        // If the old metrics MBean is present then the connector will try to unregister it
        // upon shutdown.
        registered = true;
    }
    catch (JMException | InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to register the MBean '" + name + "'", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn’t Debezium have an option not to register an MBean?

Comment: Apparently it doesn't!

Comment: It’s a strange decision of author of this code to bail out from any problem with an exception, but to silently continue when `getPlatformMBeanServer()` returns `null`. But don’t let this distract you from the reality: [`getPlatformMBeanServer()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.management/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getPlatformMBeanServer()) never returns `null`. This is not foreseen. The `getPlatformMBeanServer()` would fail with a `NullPointerException` if `MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer()` returned `null`.

Comment: The only solution would be to patch this method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a single Debezium SQL Server connector for this, and use the `table.include.list` property on the connector to list the two tables you want to capture.

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-property-table-include-list

Comment: It wouldn't properly publish initial data when adding a new table to an existing `table.include.list`.

Comment: Incremental snapshoting supports that. https://debezium.io/blog/2021/10/07/incremental-snapshots/ We ended up not wanting initial snapshot data on the topics at all and do initial loads of the data through another channel (AWS DMS and on demand Step Functions). The bottom line is you cannot add two connecors with the same name or you will get this error. If you really want it to be two connecors  they just need to have different names. Connector per table in the same DB feel like an antipattern in Debezium.